# Catching/hijacking stdout in haskell

Tags: haskell, stdout, handle

How can I define 'catchOutput' so that running main outputs only 'bar'?

That is, how can I access both the output stream (stdout) and the actual output of an io action separately?

```
catchOutput :: IO a -> IO (a,String)
catchOutput = undefined

doSomethingWithOutput :: IO a -> IO ()
doSomethingWithOutput io = do
   (_ioOutp, stdOutp) <- catchOutput io
   if stdOutp == "foo"
      then putStrLn "bar"
      else putStrLn "fail!"

main = doSomethingWithOutput (putStr "foo")
```

The best hypothetical "solution" I've found so far includes diverting stdout, [inspired by this](http://nominolo.blogspot.com/2010/04/haskell-tip-redirect-stdout-in-haskell.html), to a file stream and then reading from that file (*Besides being super-ugly I haven't been able to read directly after writing from a file. Is it possible to create a "custom buffer stream" that doesn't have to store in a file?*). Although that feels 'a bit' like a side track.

Another angle seems to use 'hGetContents stdout' if that is supposed to do what I think it should. But I'm not given permission to read from stdout. Although googling it seems to show that it has been [used](http://www.google.se/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hGetContents%20stdout#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=hGetContents%20stdout&pbx=1&oq=hGetContents%20stdout&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2047925l2047925l0l2048402l1l1l0l0l0l0l134l134l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4dde7fad0d5b288a&biw=1366&bih=680).

Comment: Depending on your use case, and whether portability is an issue you could use this experimental library:
    https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-posix-redirect-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Posix-Redirect.html

Answer (score 6):

I used the following function for an unit test of a function that prints to stdout.

```
import GHC.IO.Handle
import System.IO
import System.Directory

catchOutput :: IO () -> IO String
catchOutput f = do
  tmpd <- getTemporaryDirectory
  (tmpf, tmph) <- openTempFile tmpd "haskell_stdout"
  stdout_dup <- hDuplicate stdout
  hDuplicateTo tmph stdout
  hClose tmph
  f
  hDuplicateTo stdout_dup stdout
  str <- readFile tmpf
  removeFile tmpf
  return str
```

I am not sure about the in-memory file approach, but it works okay for a small amount of output with a temporary file.

Answer (score 6):

There are some packages on Hackage that promise to do that : io-capture and silently. silently seems to be maintained and works on Windows too (io-capture only works on Unix). With silently, you use capture :

```
import System.IO.Silently

main = do
   (output, _) <- capture $ putStr "hello"
   putStrLn $ output ++ " world"
```

Note that it works by redirecting output to a temporary file and then read it... But as long as it works !

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a writer monad instead? For example,

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

doSomethingWithOutput :: WriterT String IO a -> IO ()
doSomethingWithOutput io = do
   (_, res) <- runWriterT io
   if res == "foo"
      then putStrLn "bar"
      else putStrLn "fail!"

main = doSomethingWithOutput (tell "foo")
```

Alternatively, you could modify your inner action to take a `Handle` to write to instead of `stdout`. You can then use something like [knob](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/knob/latest/doc/html/Data-Knob.html) to make an in-memory file handle which you can pass to the inner action, and check its contents afterward.

Comment: Thing is, I can't really do much about the io argument in my actual code. That would require redesigning the outwards behavior. The "client application" is supposed to send/pass io actions (as arguments).

So at some point or another I will have to use something like 'catchOutput'. So the writer monad isn't really applicable to my problem..

Knob on the other hand seems potentially useful. :)

Comment: @worldsayshi You seem to misunderstand hammar's suggestion.  Notice he didn't use the `Writer` monad, but a `WriterT a IO` monad - so you can still call your `IO` action using `liftIO io`.

Comment: I made a correction to my code, sorry about that. Probably some confusion by that. What I'm firstly looking for is the text ending up in stdout. That what is _now_ 'res', in my example. I don't see how liftIO can give me access to that. Then I also want the ouput from actually running the io action as well. That is currently the ignored output from 'catchOutput'.

If I get an 'IO ()' as an argument lifting it will give me a 'm ()'.

Comment: Changed the name of 'res' to 'stdOutp'.

Answer (score 1):

As @hammar pointed out, you can use a knob to create an in-memory file, but you can also use `hDuplicate` and `hDuplicateTo` to change `stdout` to the memory file, and back again.  Something like the following completely untested code:

```
catchOutput io = do
  knob <- newKnob (pack [])
  let before = do
        h <- newFileHandle knob "<stdout>" WriteMode
        stdout' <- hDuplicate stdout
        hDuplicateTo h stdout
        hClose h
        return stdout'
      after stdout' = do
        hDuplicateTo stdout' stdout
        hClose stdout'
  a <- bracket_ before after io
  bytes <- Data.Knob.getContents knob
  return (a, unpack bytes)
```

Comment: Hmm, now that I actually installed `Data.Knob`, I can't get this method to work.  The call to `hDuplicateTo` fails when trying to duplicate the knob handle to `stdout`, with the following error: `Wots: <stdout>: hDuplicateTo: illegal operation (handles are incompatible)`.