# Subtle bug in Haskell tests involving Tasty, stdout capture, and the unix terminal

Tags: debugging, unix, haskell, pipe, stdout

I'm writing a language interpreter in Haskell, and for the most part it works (hooray!). But some of the tests fail in an odd way that depends on whether stdout is sent to the terminal or a pipe...

I'm using [tasty-golden](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-golden) to test the REPL. There are text files with pasted REPL sessions like this:

```
Welcome to the ShortCut interpreter!
Type :help for a list of the available commands.
shortcut >> v1 = "one"
shortcut >> v2 = "two"
shortcut >> v3 = [v1, v2]
shortcut >> :show
v1 = "one"
v2 = "two"
v3 = [v1, v2]
shortcut >> :rdepends v1
v3 = [v1, v2]
shortcut >> :quit
Bye for now!
```

I have a function that reads those files and splits them into user input (anything after `shortcut >>`) and what the program should print to stdout. It passes the input lines to the REPL, captures stdout using the [silently](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently) package, intercalates them, and checks that the combined output is the same as that file.

Everything works, but only if I pipe the overall program output through `less`! When printing directly to the terminal, certain lines slip through and are actually printed, then the tests fail because they aren't part of the captured output.

I think it might be a bug in the interaction between Tasty and Silently, which both do fancy things with terminal output, but have no idea how to debug it or write a reproducible example.

Here's the complete output run in three different ways:

- [Copied directly from the terminal](http://lpaste.net/355894)
- [Piped through `less` and copied from the terminal](http://lpaste.net/355892)
- [Piped through `tee` and copied from the resulting file](http://lpaste.net/355893)

As you can see:

- Each `FAIL` is preceded by printing part of the REPL output to the terminal instead of capturing it
- `less` somehow gets around that and the tests pass
- `tee` misses the printed bits (they end up in terminal but not the file)

Any ideas about what could be going on? I can post any parts of the code you think might be relevant, but didn't want to muddy the question with hundreds and hundreds of mostly-unrelated lines.

Update: tried replacing Silently's `hCapture_` with this function from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664017/429898):

```
catchOutput :: IO () -> IO String
catchOutput action = do
  tmpd <- getTemporaryDirectory
  (tmpf, tmph) <- openTempFile tmpd "haskell_stdout"
  stdout_dup <- hDuplicate stdout
  hDuplicateTo tmph stdout
  hClose tmph
  action
  hDuplicateTo stdout_dup stdout
  str <- readFile tmpf
  removeFile tmpf
  return str
```

Unfortunately it does the same thing.

Update 2:

Well, figured it out. Sorry for everyone who tried to puzzle through it, as I don't think I gave enough information! The bug was in my REPL monad, which was defined like this:

```
type ReplM a = StateT CutState (MaybeT (InputT IO)) a

runReplM :: ReplM a -> CutState -> IO (Maybe CutState)
runReplM r s = runInputT defaultSettings $ runMaybeT $ execStateT r s

prompt :: String -> ReplM (Maybe String)
prompt = lift . lift . getInputLine

print :: String -> ReplM ()
print = lift . lift . outputStrLn
```

I noticed that all the erroneous prints came from functions that use `print`, whereas a couple cases where I used `liftIO . putStrLn` instead worked as expected. So I just redefined `print` as that:

```
print :: String -> ReplM ()
print = liftIO . putStrLn
```

I still don't really get *why* the other version didn't work though, so I'll give the answer to whoever can explain it. `outputStrLn` is defined in [Haskeline.hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.6.3/src/System/Console/Haskeline.hs).

Comment: i think it might be difficult to debug this without a minimal working repro of the bug with pasted code

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was hoping it's a known terminal issue, but guess not. I'll work on one.

Comment: Instead of intercepting stdout from your process, have you considered just writing to a different handle (e.g. a file?)  Glancing at the source code, `silently` will just redirect output to a temporary file if it cannot find a `null` handle to which to pipe the output; just do this yourself, and skip the whole 'redirecting stdout' think.

Comment: I was considering switching to the Writer monad instead, but putting it off because I still find monad transformers pretty difficult. Maybe redirecting to a file would be a good middle ground.

Comment: You don't need a writer monad; you can just pass then handle around as an argument. Sometimes plain and straight-forward functional programming is easier…