# Simple unit tests using Cabal instead of using diff and make

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to rewrite my shell testing code for my Haskell application to use only Haskell and Cabal. (for portability reasons)

Current testing schema looks like this

```
make      ->    binary                                     ->  ok or fail
make test ->    diff $(binary test-in) test-supposed-out   ->
```

I would like to have something like

```
cabal build  ->  binary                                             ->  ok or fail
cabal test   ->  ...testing with test-in and test-supposed-out...   ->
```

What is the easiest way to do this please?

Thanks.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-golden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tasty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty) is a simple and versatile framework in which to run various kinds of tests. (I mostly use it [for](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-quickcheck) [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) tests, which – if you haven't yet – I highly recommend to check out as well.)

The particular kind of testing you're asking about is called (at least in Tasty) a *golden* test. So, for instance if the program you want to test was

```
module ComplicatedProc where

import System.IO
import System.Environment (getArgs)

complicatedProc :: String -> Handle -> IO ()
complicatedProc input outHandle = do
   hPutStr outHandle $ drop 37 input ++ take 46 input

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [inpFp] <- getArgs
  input <- readFile inpFp
  complicatedProc input stdout
```

then you could change this into a Tasty test `test/golden.hs`:

```
import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.Golden

import ComplicatedProc (complicatedProc)

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
 complicAlgo_input <- readFile "test-in"
 let complicAlgo_outFp = "test-supposed-out"
 defaultMain $ testGroup "Tests" -- †
   [ goldenVsFile "complicatedAlgo (golden)"
      "test-supposed-out" complicAlgo_outFp
      ( withFile complicAlgo_outFp WriteMode
            $ complicatedProc complicAlgo_input )
   ]
```

Use a `.cabal` file like

```
cabal-version:       >=1.10

name:                compli-algo
version:             5.7.6.8
build-type:          Simple
-- ...

library
  exposed-modules:     ComplicatedProc
  build-depends:       base
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite compli-algo-goldentest
  main-is:         golden.hs
  type:            exitcode-stdio-1.0
  build-depends:       base
                       , compli-algo
                       , tasty >=1.4 && <1.5
                       , tasty-golden >=2.3 && <2.4
  hs-source-dirs:   test
```

If the program you want to test has outputting to `stdout` hard-coded (e.g. in form of `print` statements) then you may need to [hack around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447666/catching-hijacking-stdout-in-haskell) a bit.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>There's no real need to have a `testGroup` at all here, but in practice you'll probably want to have multiple tests in that file. Tasty allows you to create an arbitrary *tree of tests*, in whatever hierarchical order is useful.</sub>